# How to bind iOS API to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, swig

I am familiar with the good old Swig and I had a look at AppMobi but I am still wondering what's best practice to bind my own iOS API to JavaScript.

Thanks

Update, its about a larger API and can not be just triggered via network, SDM or similar.

Comment: I don't think this is really something SWIG can do - you need to expose your API across an HTTP connection, not just between two languages.

Comment: Thanks, but no. I need to bind it to native iOS without any server.